# How to validate high precision GPS systems location

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, accuracy, precision, validation

I am currently working with a high precision RTK-GPS system which claims to be able to reach centimetre level accuracy, I am looking for a way to validate that it is actually reaching that precision and doesn't produce systematic errors etc.

My initial thought was to look for places nearby that had very precisely defined coordinates to compare the system against but I am struggling to find any (I live in Cambridge, UK). Any other ideas for how to go about validating it?

Comment: You could try the "repeatability" method.  Find  a location that is easy to access on a daily basis and also easy to identify (mark it with paint or a nail) and collect several observations on that same location over the course of a day or a few days.  Compare the results to see if each visit produces the same or similar results.

Comment: You can find the OS Benchmarks for the UK to find known locations near you:  https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/benchmarks/